# Как передать путь с пробелами

Tags: java

Не удается вызовать архиватор из Program Files.
Ищет с:/Program. Как экранировать пробел.

```
Process proc1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start /wait c:/Program Files/winrar/rar.exe x d:/temp/111/1.rar d:/temp/111");
    proc1.waitFor();
```

Comment: C:/Program\ Files

Comment: Process proc1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start /wait \"c:/Program Files/winrar/rar.exe\" x d:/temp/111/1.rar d:/temp/111");
    proc1.waitFor();

Answer (score 2):

Вот так попробуйте

```
Process proc1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start /wait \"c:/Program Files/winrar/rar.exe\" x d:/temp/111/1.rar d:/temp/111"); proc1.waitFor();
```

Answer (score -1):

Спасибо. На основе предложенного заэкранировал только пробел

```
Process proc1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start /wait c:/Program\" \"Files/winrar/rar.exe x d:/temp/111/1.rar d:/temp/111");
```

Comment: Мне кажется вариант с экранированием кавычками каждого пробела сомнительная. Лучше весь путь в кавычки оборачивать как было предложено в другом ответе

Comment: Не работает ни один из предложенных вариантов.

Comment: Попробуйте слеши развернуть, / поменять на \\